# How to insert blank value in SQL database date column?

Tags: java, sql

I have one database in which there is one column named START_TS of type (datetime,not null).
I wrote one program in java where I want to insert a blank value in that column but its taking
'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' as the value.

```
statement.executeUpdate("insert into tableName(START_TS) values(CAST(START_TS as varchar(100)))");
```

Please suggest the casting mechanism where i can insert blank value in that column.

Thanks

Comment: Insert `NULL` if column constraints is `NULL`.

    insert into tableName(START_TS) values (NULL)

Comment: you cannot insert blank in the case of date you can use null.

Comment: It cannot be done, you can add null, if you remove not null contraint , otherwise I dont suppose there is any option

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic473146-338-1.aspx

Comment: You cannot insert Null value either as there is a constraint not null. I suggest instead of blank value you add '1970-01-01' by default its more or less like a null.

Comment: @Patton In this case the value '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' is being inserted .. which is better than Unix epoch for date column.

Comment: That's the default value for "not null" datetime in your SQL database engine (yes, that's the *blank* datetime). What do you really need?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza - What i am looking for is that when in my program i give "" argument to be inserted in the database column of type (datetime,not null) but its taking default value as '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'.

Comment: @Ars, that's the default behavior that your SQL database engine has. You can't do anything against it but to remove the `NOT NULL` constraint, then you could insert a `NULL` value. There is no *blank* (white spaces or `''`) data for `DATETIME` fields, that concept can apply only for `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` (and derived) datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

If you using MYSQL which the syntax appears to point at; you could do the following:

> ALLOW_INVALID_DATES
>
> Do not perform full checking of dates. Check only that the month is in
>   the range from 1 to 12 and the day is in the range from 1 to 31. This
>   is very convenient for Web applications where you obtain year, month,
>   and day in three different fields and you want to store exactly what
>   the user inserted (without date validation). This mode applies to DATE
>   and DATETIME columns. It does not apply TIMESTAMP columns, which
>   always require a valid date.
>
> This mode is implemented in MySQL 5.0.2. Before 5.0.2, this was the
>   default MySQL date-handling mode. As of 5.0.2, the server requires
>   that month and day values be legal, and not merely in the range 1 to
>   12 and 1 to 31, respectively. With strict mode disabled, invalid dates
>   such as '2004-04-31' are converted to '0000-00-00' and a warning is
>   generated. With strict mode enabled, invalid dates generate an error.
>   To permit such dates, enable ALLOW_INVALID_DATES.

However like everyone has said in the comments, it's not possible to stick a " " in a field whose data type is DATETIME.